# The conversion of a datetimeoffset data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, datetimeoffset

Using SQL Server 2008.I have a table called User which has a column `LastLogindata` with `datetimeoffset` datatype

The following query works on production server but not on replication server.

```
select top 10 CAST(LastLoginDate AS DATETIME)  from User.
```

I am getting the following error.The conversion of a datetimeoffset data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Thanks

Comment: There may be a different default date format on the other machine.  It may be trying to convert a number like 20 to a month.

Comment: production server version : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Replication server version : 
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Can you post  sample data for the column LastLogindata

Comment: Hi! Steve, How do I check default date format on the machine?

Comment: Sample Data : 2012-07-11 09:46:49.4457873 -05:00,
2012-07-11 11:58:13.8353048 -05:00,
2011-08-11 18:32:10.1738934 -05:00,
2012-07-11 11:50:53.5568726 -05:00

Comment: both servers have dateformat mdy

Comment: It appears like service pack2 is causing the issue.

Comment: Just encounter a similar error trying to convert a date plus some strings to a datetime. Query works fine in SSMS and with pymssql, but gives error with ODBC and JDBC. This only happens after _upgrading_ to SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 (10.50.4000.0), and is still not fixed in CU2 (10.50.4263.0). SQL Server is such a catastrophic failure.

Comment: In my case, changing from `CAST` to `CONVERT` get things to work with ODBC again. The JDBC one was just red herring, and wasn't affected.

Answer (score 4):

Check the LastLoginDate columns value like this '0001-01-01' or '0001/01/01'.

If u have means get this error ..

Try this one

```
select top 10  CAST(CASE when cast(LastLoginDate  as varchar) = '0001-01-01 00:00:00' 
                         THEN NULL ELSE GETDATE() end AS DATETIME) from User
```

Answer (score 1):

If a field in database is of type `datetimeoffset` type, then it should contain date within range `0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31`. I think the issue is the date inside your database.

Please check the official link of SQL server [Click Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way. I had an nvarchar(max) column casted as an xml and used the T-SQL expression [ISDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql) to exclude the bad rows in the where clause.

```
where cast(DataObject as xml).value('(/DataObjects/@LastLoginDate)[1]', 'varchar(10)') is not null
and isdate(cast(DataObject as xml).value('(/DataObjects/@LastLoginDate)[1]', 'varchar(10)')) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server 2016, I used:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME2, DateValueColumn)
```

This worked for values that were giving errors when trying to convert to DATETIME, giving the message "The conversion of a datetimeoffset data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." The offending values had dates of 0001-01-01, as a previous answer has mentioned.

Not sure if this works on SQL Server 2008 though.